# How do I make a button in Android scale instead of cropping?

Tags: android, xml

I have three buttons in a LinearLayout.

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:background="@drawable/color_button"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:background="@drawable/color_button"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:background="@drawable/color_button"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

The button image is wider than 1/3 of the space available for the layout. Right now they're displayed at 100% scale, with the edges cropped off on the left and right. I'd like them to scale down to fit in the space available. I've tried fiddling with adjustViewBounds and scaleType, and nothing I change there seems to have any effect at all.

Comment: You should use **smaller** pictures. By the way, use `layout_weight="1"` instead of `0.3` - Android will assign the same weitgh to all. `Counter-intuitive`, but it works well.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the property `scaleType`? Just a hint...

Comment: Also, have you ever heard of `different density buckets`?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be something silly. Changing from android:background to android:src made scaleType work as expected.

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:src="@drawable/color_button"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:src="@drawable/color_button"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:src="@drawable/color_button"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Because `scaleType` doesn't work on the `background` attribute.